# How to create a factory of context manager class

Tags: python-3.x

Working with python3

I have an existing class which connects to a remote directory server

```
class ldap:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def __enter__(self):
    print("ldap connecting: %s" % self.name)

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    print("ldap disconnecting: %s" % self.name)
```

I am trying to create another class which will have multiple instances of this LDAP class.

Basically

```
class driver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connections = {}
        self.count = count(1)
        self.connector = ldap_connector()

    def junk(self, name):
        self.connections[next(self.count)] = self.connector.get_me_connected(name)
```

These are my failed attempts to come up with the `ldap_connector` class :)

```
class ldap_connector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connections = []

#    def __enter__(self):
#        print("ldap_connector init")
#        with ldap(self.name) as p:
#            yield p    # Yield doesn't work well in __enter__

#    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
#        print("ldap_connector de-init")

    def get_me_connected(self, name):
        try:
            while True:
                with ldap(name) as pc:
                    self.connections.append(pc)
                    yield pc
        finally:
            for conn in self.connections:
                print("Dumping conn")


#def get_me_connected():
#    def _connect(name):
#        print("Getting connected with {}".format(name))
#        with ldap_connector(name) as pc:
#            yield pc
#    return _connect
```

At this point I am not sure how to achieve this

Any suggestions on what would be the best approach ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could come up with as a crude factory, more of a garage ;)

```
class ldap_connector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connections = {}

    def get_me_connected(self, name):
        pc = ldap(name)
        self.connections[name] = pc.__enter__()
        return pc

    def destruct(self):
        for conn in self.connections:
            conn.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

The issue with this is that the caller needs to call `destruct()` explicitly

I feel there would be a more pythonic way of making this a `contextmanager` class in itself and it keeps generating `class ldap` objects when `get_me_connected()` is called